# ggplot: How to scale x axis with many factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a chart that shows certain information per week.
The dataframe looks like this (over 100 rows in total):

```
     week french tickets
1 2016-13 French     181
2 2016-13  Other    2066
3 2016-14 French     610
4 2016-14  Other    6805
5 2016-15 French     616
6 2016-15  Other    6587
```

The `week` column is factor type with each week representing one level.

I want to make an area chart with ggplot with the weeks on the x axis. The issue is that every single factor is shown in the x axis and it becomes illegible.

How can I show just a few weeks? So for example, show only one week factor every 10?

This is my current code:

```
ggplot(support.week, aes(x=week, y=tickets, fill=french, group=french)) +
  geom_area(position="stack", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual("Languages", values = c("blue","tomato")) +
  xlab("Week - Year") +
  ylab("# Tickets") +
  ggtitle("Tickets per week") +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color="grey")
  )
```

I suspect that I need to use `scale_x_discrete` but I cannot figure out how to do it.

[Area chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vopAT.png)

Comment: if you convert your year-week column into a `Date` object, you can then use `scale_x_datetime`

Comment: Do the weeks encompass more than one year?  If not, it seems most straightforward to make a numeric `week` variable based on the last two numbers in your current variable rather than working with a factor.  If it does encompass multiple years, maybe convert it to a `Date` variable instead of a categorical variable.

Comment: With `Date` dates are still stored internally with days information. I'm aggregating information by week. That is why I changed to factor. I don't know if there is a better way to just use week number information and ignore the day.